# Table Rates by Weight, edit the Calculation

Tags: magento

Thanks to [Joseph Mastey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325663/magento-table-rates-by-weight-edit-the-calculation), I was able to create a module for Magento that calculated shipping by the heaviest item, rather than the total weight of a shopping cart.

Using this:

```
class MyNamespace_MyModule_Model_Shipping extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping {

    public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request) {
        $maxWeight = 0;
        foreach($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
            $maxWeight = max($maxWeight, $item->getRowWeight());
        }
        $request->setPackageWeight($maxWeight);
    
        return parent::collectRates($request);
    }
}
```

However, now, it has stopped working, and it is back to calculating shipping based on total weight. I have run no updates, and was wondering if anyone had a clue as to why this function no longer works? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there anyone else who has access to your magento's admin panel?

Comment: Thanks for helping. I've just resolved this actually. Found some lines in the Matrixrate addon by Webshopapps that was overriding my hacked weight calculations. Namely: $request->setPackageWeight($request->getFreeMethodWeight()); I've commented this out, not the perfect solution I know, but it has restored my desired weight calculations. Yey!

Comment: That's ok, just post your comment as an answer yourself and accept it.

Comment: Dumb question, how do I answer my own question?

Comment: On this question page, if you scroll down a bit, you shall see a text box "Your Answer". There is where you write your answer, and *accept* it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just resolved this myself actually. Found some lines in the Matrixrate addon by Webshopapps that was overriding my hacked weight calculations. Namely: $request->setPackageWeight($request->getFreeMethodWeight()); I've commented this out, not the perfect solution I know, but it has restored my desired weight calculations.